# Metadata-Extractor orientation gyroscope

Tags: orientation, gyroscope, metadata-extractor

I would like to extract the following metadata (user name, date, time, orientation and gyroscope) from photos taken indoors with a smartphone camera. Can Metadata Extractor extract the gyroscope values for each photo from the EXIF file? The value of the gyroscope will determine the tilt of the phone - whether it's pointed at the floor, wall or ceiling.  Thanks.

Comment: Orientation data isn't something I've seen before, but it might be in there. What camera model are you using?

Comment: As an aside, gyroscopes measure angular velocity, not orientation. In tandem with an accelerometer a system might estimate the orientation through probabilistic filtering, but that data won't be direct gyroscope output. Rather, it's derived data.

Comment: Thanks for the replies Drew. I realise (now) that my question wasn't very sensible. The essence of my idea is to take a photo with a smart phone indoors and then at a later point be able to locate the position, (including direction and orientation) of where the phone was when the photo was taken in a 3D model of the building. I realise now that its the sensors in the phone i should be looking at and not the EXIF data of the image. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The image might contain some GPS data in Exif.